# knockout.js foreach - display item content on page

Tags: debugging, data-binding, foreach, knockout.js

For debug purposes, I'm trying to display the current content inside a foreach loop like this, but I'm getting an "Unable to parse bindings" error.  You can see my atteping inside the 'pre' tag at the bottom of the item. Any suggestions for how to properly display this?

```
<!-- ko foreach: criteria -->
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: myVal"></span>               
    <label><input type="radio" value="AND" data-bind="checked: logicGate">AND</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="OR" data-bind="checked: logicGate">OR</label>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</a>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Hey Adam, can you post as a jsfiddle.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that I'm passing in an html element (which causes the parsing error) and it can't be parsed.  I'll have to use some other form of debug.  Also, just by putting it into JSFiddle I was able to see that my AND/OR radio stuff is working, so this was as good as an answer.  Thanks as always, Ian.

Comment: Cool. You should post that as the answer and accept it. Id suggest console.log as alternative for debugging, that or firebug breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing elements into the object's constructor and they can't be serialized by the ko.toJSON method.